# What command do I use to show the arms of an armor stand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to make an armor stand's arms show so it can hold something. I'm trying to find out the command because I'm working on a battle scene with the battlers as armor stands, and to make it look as if they were actualy fighting, they would need arms.

Answer (score 3):

The command you would use is `/summon ArmorStand ~ ~1 ~ {ShowArms:1}`  This will give it arms at the location you use the command.

Comment: Or if you want to make an existing Armor Stand have arms, `entitydata @e[type=ArmorStand,c=1] {ShowArms:1}` for the nearest one to you, or  `entitydata @e[type=ArmorStand,r=15] {ShowArms:1}` for all within 15 blocks of you.